# Problem with Laravel/Installer + Composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

How are you doing?

Well, I'm having an issue trying to install laravel on my production server. If I run the installation command, at the end of the process it returns me an error like:

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                                                     
  File at "/home/sites/.composer/vendor/symfony/polyfill-php73/Resources/stubs/JsonException.php" could not be parsed as PHP, it may be binary or corrupted
```

The server has two PHP versions installed, 5.5.38 and 7.3.16. I'm currently running it with the newest version using the command `path/to/php73 ./composer.phar global require laravel/installer`

I already deleted all files, cleaned up cache, added aliases to both and even tried to install laravel directly via composer, but I got a similar error, but in other files.

I searched in lots of places but it seems like no one had this error.

I hope you guys can help me.

Regards!

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What does that linked file contain? And why do you run `composer global require` on a production server?

Comment: I don't have a clue how to debug this, do you have a suggestion? I'm just following the procedures in the laravel website. I tried to install using ```composer create-project ```and by cloning the laravel repo, but none of these worked too.

Comment: These docs surely don't tell you tu ron that on a production server ;) Better use a development server for this, and deploy your final work there

Comment: I tried to create the project on my computer, send the files to the server and run the commands, but the error persists.